# Firefox Shortens Urls in Console with dot-dot-dot (...)

Tags: javascript, firefox, devtools

I was trying to extract the URLs of certain links on a webpage, using this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="whatever"]');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
  console.log(links[i].href);
};
```

While this works well on Chrome, Firefox shortens the URLs with '...' in console, and trying to save the console content to a file uses the shortened URLs, so not useful:

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Can it be that the console is truncating only visually because the string is too long?

Comment: See [Long strings that begin with ‘http’ truncated](//discourse.mozilla.org/t/long-strings-that-begin-with-http-truncated/74089). Right-click → Copy link location. @HarunYilmaz Only long URLs are truncated.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz No, it's not just the visual presentation, using "Copy Message" or "Save all messages to file" will include the '...'

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yeah, but the whole purpose of doing this was about automating the procedure, and doing this for each entry doesn't make sense... 
My task is already done in Chrome, I just wanted to see if I can make Firefox to do it as well. Thanks!  